# Woocommerce Product Preview "too many redirects" Problem

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a woocommerce wordpress site, When adding a product, when I press the preview without publishing the product, it gives an error

> "error too many redirect".

I can preview the product after publishing, but I can't preview before publishing.

I did not change any settings and did not install any new plugins.

Solutions I've tried:

- I cleared the browser cache. (Not Work)
- I resaved the permalinks page. (Not Work)

how do i fix this problem?

Comment: If you have some SEO plugins try to disable it and see if problem is solved, if Y its misconfiguration, if N try to deactivate rest of the plugins. Actually you can find a lot of articles about it, so try all solutions, not just clearing the cache :)

Comment: Yes, have seo plugin i try it now

Comment: check these articles - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/    https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/how-to-solve-the-too-many-redirects-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: @AngelDeykov Yes, I disabled Rank Math Seo and the problem went away. But I don't know what caused it

Comment: you have a starting point now, Google will help you :)

Comment: @AngelDeykov yes it was a good start and i solved the problem thank you.

Comment: Post the solution, the seo plugin name and the solution

Comment: Update plugin: Rank Math Seo.